# Gridview image issue (Edge image not using CustomImageView)

Tags: android, gridview, android-gridview

I have an odd issue. Basically I use a custom image view which I overwrite the draw method. The draw method just writes the tag of the image object.

I have a grid of all these custom image views. The issue stems from the edge image that it renders. Basically the image does not display any text (just the image) but when I scroll out and back again the text reappears for the image. I am just asking whether there is any way to actually render the text of the edge image and not have to scroll off screen and back.

Here is the getView code for my image adaptor:

```
    @Override
    public View getView(int arg0, View arg1, ViewGroup arg2) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        CustomImageView tmp;

        if (arg1 == null) {
            tmp = new CustomImageView("", cx, true);
        } else {
            tmp = (CustomImageView) arg1;
        }

        int Dimens = (int) getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.gridParam);

        tmp.setPadding(3, 3, 3, 3);

        tmp.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(Dimens, Dimens));

        tmp.setTag("TESTIMG" + arg0);

        tmp.setImageResource(mThumbIds[arg0]);

        return tmp;
    }
}
```

And here is the code for my gridview, its just a standard creation.

```
GridView gridview = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridview);

gridview.setAdapter(new ImageAdaptor(this));
```

Hopefully you can help me out. Just curious as to why this issue is occuring, maybe I left out something.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!